# How do I configure sslContextParameters for camel-undertow to use with the rest DSL?

Tags: rest, apache-camel, undertow

currently, I'm using camel-jetty for setting up the rest DSL, it's pretty much straightforward, I create an SSLContextParameters object, and then pass it like this:

```
JettyHttpComponent jetty = context.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
jetty.setSslContextParameters(sslContextParameters);
```

and that's it, but in Undertow, there is no method whatsoever to do that, the only thing that is mentioned once in [the documentation](http://camel.apache.org/undertow.html) is that it supports the sslContextParameters option, but there's no method or anything to set such option.

How do I assign my sslContextParameters object to the Undertow component so that I can use SSL connections with the rest DSL?

By the way, I have tried setting an UndertowComponent object and adding the option as a component parameter, and also tried adding the option in EndpointProperties through restConfiguration() to no avail.

I have also browsed the github source code for 2.16.1, which is the latest in maven central, and I only see a reference to an ssl context in UndertowRegistry and the setSslContext setter is never even used anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set SSL on the component level on camel-undertow. I have logged a ticket to make this possible in upcoming release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9559

You would need to configure the SSL as a endpointProperty in the rest-dsl configuration. You can find more details at: http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl. And you would need to add the sslContextParameters to the Camel registry beforehand, so the endpointProperty can lookup it by its id.

Answer (score 1):

SSL context can be assigned in following way:

```
    UndertowComponent uc = new UndertowComponent(context);

    KeyStoreParameters trust_ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    trust_ksp.setResource("/cacerts.jks");
    trust_ksp.setPassword("changeit");
    TrustManagersParameters trustp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    trustp.setKeyStore(trust_ksp);

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setTrustManagers(trustp);
    uc.setSslContextParameters(scp);
```